# Drop Down Menu in c# (position and use)

Tags: c#, forms, button, dropdown, linqpad

For my project in school, I have to create a window and program that has a menu, and for the menu, I need to have a drop down menu.
The drop down menu works and all, however, I cannot seem to get it to go into the lower part of my window.
Here is my code:

```
    var MenuWindow = new Form();
    MenuWindow.Height = 300;
    MenuWindow.Width = 300;
    MenuWindow.Text = "Menu";

    ToolBarButton Numbers = new ToolBarButton("Number of players");                         
    ToolBar DropDownMenu = new ToolBar();                                           
    MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("1");
    MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("2");                             
    ContextMenu ContentsOfMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] { menuItem1, menuItem2 });
    DropDownMenu.Buttons.Add(Numbers);
    Numbers.Style = ToolBarButtonStyle.DropDownButton;
    Numbers.DropDownMenu = ContentsOfMenu;
    DropDownMenu.Left = 95;
    DropDownMenu.Top = 215;
    DropDownMenu.Width = 100;
    DropDownMenu.Height = 10;

    MenuWindow.Controls.Add(DropDownMenu);

    MenuWindow.Show();
```

As you can see I have tried to add the Height, Width, Left and Top coordinates. However, this has done no difference to where the position of this drop down menu.
I have used a ToolBar and a ToolStrip and the result is the same; I cannot move the position of the button/drop down menu.

Also if you have any suggestions on how to improve my code, please do as I am new to this part of c#.

Comment: Do you have to code this manually?!  Why are you not using Visual Studio to design this visually?

Comment: Toolbars are designed to assume they belong at the top of the window.  You'll have to set its Dock property to DockStyle.None

Comment: @AZhitom, I would remove your "linqpad" tag.  Even though you might be using that tool for your project, it's not really relevant to your question.  Ironically though, it's the tag that led me here.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is that the name of your variable "DropDownMenu" is misleading.  That variable is a ToolBar, not a drop down menu.  When you're actually selecting from the drop down on your form, the control you are using is "Numbers".  "Numbers" is really what should be called "DropDownMenu".

Given this, I suspect the reason you can't change the Top and Left properties of your toolbar is because it is in fact a toolbar.  Toolbars just go at the extremes of their containers.  It never makes sense to put them in the middle.  It's odd that they even have this property, but I'm guessing that it's because they inherit from "Control".  The rendering engine must simply ignore these properties.  If you really must have this, take a look at Hans Passant's comment under your question.

I don't work too much with Windows Forms Controls, but I do recall that typically you're more likely to want "ComboBox" for this.  And put the combo box straight on your form, bypassing any toolbars.  Like this:

```
var label = 
    new Label() { 
        Text = "Players", 
        Top = 20, 
        Left = 20, 
        Width = 75 
    };

var combo = 
    new ComboBox() {
        Left = label.Left + label.Width,
        Top = label.Top,
        Width = 150,
        Height = 10        
    };

combo.Items.Add("1");
combo.Items.Add("2");

var MenuWindow = 
    new Form() {
        Height = 100,
        Width = 300,
        Text = "Menu"
    };

MenuWindow.Controls.Add(combo);
MenuWindow.Controls.Add(label);

MenuWindow.Show();
```

Also, since you're new, note the different style.  It's not particularly better, but it's worth knowing about.  Setting properties in this manner helps me block things together better.  Also, it's generally okay to use the "var" keyword when it's painfully obvious what kind of variable you have.  So, for instance, it is very clear that combo is a ComboBox.  Consequently I just use "var".  When it's even a little unclear, then write out the actual type.